# Create an external table Informix

Tags: sql, informix

I am trying to create an external table in Informix.

```
create external table test_table(cols varchar(10)) 
using ( datafiles('C:/sample.txt'), format 'delimited', deluxe);
```

But it gives me an error :

```
[Error Code: -26174, SQL State: IX000]  Incorrect DATAFILE entry C:/sample.txt.
```

Can anyone suggest me the right syntax for path entry...

I have also tried.

```
load from "C:\sample.txt" insert into test_table;
```

Which gives me a syntax error. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the **create external table**
Did you check the correct syntax at the manual? ([here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2053.htm?lang=en))

At datafiles keyword, you don't use the correct syntax. 
This probably will work.

```
create external table test_table(cols varchar(10)) 
using ( datafiles('DISK:C:\sample.txt'), format 'delimited', deluxe);
```

About the **load**
It isn't a native command from the engine, is a specific command of **dbaccess** utility.
So, if you aren't using dbaccess, it will not work.
BTW, the syntax of your load is correct...

Comment: Thanks, Cein. I have tried it but it gives me an error saying 'No Resource Permission'. I can create a normal table though. What might be going wrong? Also, is there anyway to directly read the file into a normal table instead of external table? Please let me know.

Here's the error..
  "09:52:31  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -388, SQL State: IX000]  No resource permission."

Comment: I think there is some permission issue on my side but the above one works.. Thanks again!! Let me know if there is any other way to load the data from a text file instead of using external tables.